# Как отключить логи в Apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache

Я отключил логи как `#CustomLog` `#ErrorLog "logs/error_log"` в httpd.conf запись логов в `/opt/lampp/logs/error_log` остановилось 
При отправке много GET запросов на сайт делаю проверку командой **htop** показывает что apache, пытается записать лог хотя все отключено и в итоге нагружается машина как отключить это чтобы не было запись логов ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему вы решили, что машина нагружается именно от записи логов?

Comment: как видно на скришоте apache создает процесс при каждом посищении сайта если флудить GET запросом мащина перегружается на 100% сверху показанно Mem - оперативная память

Comment: Почему вы решили, что всё сказанное вами имеет какое-то отношение к записи логов?

Comment: Что за бред вы несете простите, явно видно что процесс связан с логами можете увидеть .../error_log он пытается записать лог как бы

Comment: Почему вы решили, что связь процесса с логами вызывают тормоза? Почему вы решили, что логи могут тормозить? Почему вы решили, что кто-то что-то пытается записать — может, этот лог никак не используется и отображается среди аргументов командной строки просто так и игнорируется процессом. Вам бы изучить основы линукса, прежде чем делать такие смелые заявления про «бред»

Comment: То есть когда я посылаю много GET запросов машина сама по себе грузит RAM на 100% сам по себе начинает тормозить ?)))

Comment: Не рассматривали вариант, что ваш сайт неоптимизированный и зависает из-за слишком долгой обработки запросов? При чём тут логи-то?

Comment: Причем тут это? сайт грузится за 1.5 секунд тут идет речь про DDOS атак а именно GET FLOOD при тестах машина оперативки повышается до 100% в консоле наблюдаются что апаче создает просессы для каждого запроса

Comment: Ну вот вы сами и рассказали, что логи ни при чём. Разумеется, апач и должен создавать отдельный процесс для каждого запроса — это его стандартное поведение. Если вам это поведение не нравится, копайтесь в настройках выбранного вами Apache MPM или замените MPM на другой — но логи-то всё равно ни при чём.

Comment: 1. Посмотрите через `sudo tail /opt/lampp/logs/error_log` последние строчки лога, если не уверены, что логи надежно отключены. 2. Найти проблемные места можно через XHProfiler - если у вас PHP. 3. Если профайлер выявил, что тормоза в вызову `mysql*` функций - делайте профайл SQL запросов через pt-query-digest